# Assertion in json response

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, assertions

I am getting below json response:

```
{"participantUID": "000000000004871"}
```

I want to do assertion on participantUID.

My code:

```
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

assert jsonSlurper.participantUID == expectedparticipant
```

but I am getting error: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:`

Please help me out. thanks

Comment: `println` the `ResponseMessage` to verify if you get what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure since you don't copy the complete `MissingPropertyExceptionMessage` in your question but since you're accessing correctly the response content using `messageExchange` context variable the problem is probably that you're not defining the `expectedparticipant` in your `Script assertion` try with:

```
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def expectedparticipant = '000000000004871'

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
assert jsonSlurper.participantUID == expectedparticipant
```